# Google sheets easily put a similar sheet name in a variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

May I ask if there is a way for me to easily put all the sheet name (well, most likely `SF2` sheet) in this variable? I do have like 10 similar `SF2` sheets.

```
var sheetNames = ["School Form 1 (SF1)", "SEPT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "OCT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "OCT-School Form 2 (SF2)", ........, "School Form 5 (SF5)"];
```

I'm currently working in hiding rows. Here's the code:

```js
var startRow = 11;
var colToCheck = 2;

// This script is the same with your "HideRows".
function script_HideRows() {
  var sheetNames = ["School Form 1 (SF1)", "SEPT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "OCT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "School Form 5 (SF5)"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetNames.includes(sheetName)) {
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
    }
  });
}
```

What should I put to make the script still work in all of the sheets? Should I just enter it all or is there an easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TDLR**

### Explanation:

Get **all** the sheet names,

**replace:**

```
var sheetNames = ["School Form 1 (SF1)", "SEPT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "OCT-School Form 2 (SF2)", "School Form 5 (SF5)"];
```

**with:**

```
var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sh=>sh.getSheetName());
```

Then, if you only want to get the sheets that contain `SF2`:

**replace:**

```
if (sheetNames.includes(sheetName))
```

**with:**

```
if (sheetNames.includes('SF2'))
```

---

If you want to have multiple filters, try this logic:

```
if (sheetNames.includes('SF2') || sheetNames.includes('SF5'))
```

The latter will evaluate to `true` for all the sheets that contain `SF2` or `SF5`.

### Solution 1:

```
var startRow = 11;
var colToCheck = 2;

// This script is the same with your "HideRows".
function script_HideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sh=>sh.getSheetName());
  
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);                 
    if (sheetName.includes('SF2')) {
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows);
    }
  });
}
```

### Solution 2:

Another approach would be to filter on `SF2` at the point you define the `sheetNames` array. Using this approach you don't need to iterate over all sheets, but only the relevant ones (that contain `SF2`). Therefore, you don't need an `if` condition in the `forEach` loop.

```
var startRow = 11;
var colToCheck = 2;

// This script is the same with your "HideRows".
function script_HideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sh=>sh.getSheetName())
                   .filter(sheetName=>sheetName.includes('SF2'))
  
  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);                 
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var elements = sheet.getRange(startRow, colToCheck, numRows).getValues();
     
      for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (shouldHideRow(sheet, i, elements[i][0])) {
          sheet.hideRows(startRow + i);
        }
      }
      // Hide the rest of the rows
      var totalNumRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
      if (totalNumRows > numRows)
        sheet.hideRows(numRows+1, totalNumRows - numRows); 
  });
}
```

Using the same logic as before, if you want multiple filters, do that:

```
var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sh=>sh.getSheetName())
                   .filter(sheetName=>sheetName.includes('SF2') || sheetName.includes('SF5'))
```