# Google sheet: Run script with similar sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm currently working with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998646/google-sheets-add-image-or-drawing-if-a-cell-contains-specific-text/65005595#65005595). The solution there works, but I still have a problem as I need to execute the script in several sheets with a similar sheet name. By similar sheet name, means I most likely have 10 sheets with a name which includes "SF2". I tried to modify the code with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708410/6729785), but I can't make it work.

The following is the code that works on one sheet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  let r = e.range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == "SEPT-School Form 2 (SF2)" && r == "t") {
    let col = e.range.getColumn();
    let row = e.range.getRow();
    sheet.getRange(13,40).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row,col));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You can simply use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check whether the sheet name includes the word `SF2`.

**Solution:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  let r = e.range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName().includes("SF2") && r == "t") {
    let col = e.range.getColumn();
    let row = e.range.getRow();
    sheet.getRange(13,40).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row,col));
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been working with the `includes` earlier, but it seems like I wrote the script wrong, that's why `includes` don't work for me, but it works now so thank you!

Comment: @cjvdg happy coding :)